# How to load external data in polymer component?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am developing a polymer component so:

```
<dom-module id="form-list">
<template>
  <div>{{title}}</div>
  <form>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{inputAndLabel}}">
      <div>
        <label>{{item.tag}}</label>
        <input type="{{item.type}}" value="{{item.defaultValue}}">
      </div>
    </template>
  </form>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'form-list',
    ready: function() {
      this.title = 'Formulario: Usuario',
      this.inputAndLabel = [
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag:'Nombre' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Apellido' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag:'Email' },
        {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Dirección' },
      ];
    }
 });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

This portion of code, I am adding that inside element,

```
this.inputAndLabel = [
    {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag:'Nombre' },
    {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Apellido' },
    {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag:'Email' },
    {defaultValue: '', type:'text', tag: 'Dirección' },
  ];
```

How to load the data from another file? Or from file that is using this component `<form-list>`

Comment: Use the iron-ajax component: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax or you could also use any of your favourite JS functions, such as $.ajax from jQuery...

Comment: Thanks.  It was OK for my purpose.

Comment: You can add a property and pass values to property from parent elements to child..

Comment: You can add a property and bind values to property from parent elements to child..In parent  <form-list input-and-label={{someData}}><\form-list> and you can access that data in your iron-form component..Data will be present inside

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.